# UNABLE TO CREATE USING CSV FILE IN NEO4J

Tags: neo4j

cODE:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADER FROM "FILE:///Complication.csv" AS CSVLINE CREATE(COMPLICATIONS: COMPLICATIONS{RECORDID: CSVLINE.RECORDID, 
INSTITUTION_ID: CSVLINE.INSTITUTION_ID,
DATABASEID: CSVLINE.DATABASEID,
COMPLICATIONCODE: CSVLINE.COMPLICATIONCODE
})
```

ERROR MESSAGE:Invalid input ' ': expected 's/S' (line 1, column 21 (offset: 20))

"LOAD CSV WITH HEADER FROM "FILE:///Complication.csv" AS CSVLINE CREATE(COMPLICATIONS: COMPLICATIONS{RECORDID: CSVLINE.RECORDID, "

Comment: Maybe solve your capslock issue first.

Comment: What does the input look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate issue is a syntax error: `HEADER` should be `HEADERS`.

*You may have other issues as well if the actual headers do not have the same capitalization as in your query.*

Comment: Thanks cybersam.gotta be careful.